# jtl file is not getting parsed in jenkins for jmeter

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to run the jmeter test from Jenkins. I've already installed performance plugin and restarted the jenkins. I don't want to use any maven/ant.

Execute shell command

```
 cd /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/meineTui-QA-Test-Jmeter/workspace 
 java -jar /Users/Shared/Jenkins/apache-jmeter/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar  -n -t Login_Logout.jmx -l result.jtl
```

In the post build actions of jenkin-> publish performance test result report -> jmeter -> report files -> **/*.jtl

While I am running from jenkin the console says

```
 Performance: Failed to parse /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/meineTui-QA-Test-Jmeter/builds/2013-10-03_17-14-53/performance-reports/JMeter/result.jtl: Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

So I am not able view the result/report in the performance Report section. Any suggestion how to fix.

==================================console output=============

```
+ cd /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/meineTui-QA-Test-Jmeter/workspace 
+ java -jar /Users/Shared/Jenkins/apache-jmeter/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t Login_Logout.jmx -l result.jtl 
Creating summariser <summary>
Created the tree successfully using Login_Logout.jmx 
Starting the test @ Thu Oct 03 17:14:55 BST 2013 (1380816895721) 
Waiting for possible shutdown message on port 4445 
 summary +      2 in   4.1s =    0.5/s Avg:  2013 Min:   766 Max:  3260 Err:     0 (0.00%)   Active: 1 Started: 1 Finished: 0 
 summary +     10 in     4s =    2.5/s Avg:   392 Min:   286 Max:   573 Err:     0 (0.00%)  Active: 0 Started: 1 Finished: 1 
  summary =     12 in     8s =    1.5/s Avg:   662 Min:   286 Max:  3260 Err:     0 (0.00%) 
  Tidying up ...    @ Thu Oct 03 17:15:04 BST 2013 (1380816904307) 
 ... end of run 
 Performance: Percentage of errors greater or equal than 0% sets the build as unstable 
 Performance: Percentage of errors greater or equal than 0% sets the build as failure 
 Performance: Recording JMeter reports '**/*.jtl' 
 Performance: Parsing JMeter report file result.jtl 
 Performance: Failed to parse /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/meineTui-QA-Test-Jmeter/builds /2013-10-03_17-14-53/performance-reports/JMeter/result.jtl: Content is not allowed in prolog. 
 Finished: SUCCESS
```

## result.jtl

1380816896268,766,Login,200,OK,Group1 1-1,text,true,230,766 
1380816897071,3260,Reservations,200,OK,Group1 1-1,text,true,3295,3260 
1380816900339,335,ReservationID,200,OK,Group1 1-1,text,true,8683,335 
1380816900681,353,Weather,200,OK,Group1 1-1,text,true,2022,353 
1380816901039,563,Summary,200,OK,Group1 1-1,text,true,6528,563 
1380816901607,573,Home,200,OK,Group1 1-1,text,true,11955,573 
1380816902187,329,HolidayCountdown,200,OK,Group1 1-1,text,true,344,329 
1380816902520,375,Contacts,200,OK,Group1 1-1,text,true,2835,375 
1380816902899,286,Excursions,200,OK,Group1 1-1,text,true,237,286 
1380816903189,361,TravelAgent,200,OK,Group1 1-1,text,true,570,361 
1380816903554,319,Profile,200,OK,Group1 1-1,text,true,395,319

Comment: Now I am able to parse it. My silly mistake. 

jmeter.properties file I changed as below 

     # legitimate values: xml, csv, db.  Only xml and csv are currently supported. 

     jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml 

     jmeter.save.saveservice.data_type=true 
     jmeter.save.saveservice.label=true 
     jmeter.save.saveservice.response_code=true 

     jmeter.save.saveservice.successful=true 
     jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name=true

Comment: Maybe answer your own question with this info.

Answer (score 11):

**make the following changes in the jmeter.properties file:**

remove the comment from the following line and change csv by xml

```
#jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv
```

like this:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
```

remove the (#) comment from the following lines:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.data_type=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.label=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_code=true

jmeter.save.saveservice.successful=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name=true
```

**And change the extension of the file to be generate jtl to xml.**

[image: jenkins configuration]

Answer (score 0):

With latest versions of Jenkins Performance plugin (e.g. v1.14) you can parse both CSV and XML formats.

Depending on the format of your result files, you need to select the appropriate report type in the "Publish performance tests result report" section:

- chose "JMeter" report type if your result files are XML
- chose "JMeterCSV" report type if your result files are CSV.